# I flagged this post as 'Not Constructive' but the OP is protesting. What should I do?

Tags: support

I flagged this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577747/criteria-for-choosing-between-java-and-net-for-small-web-app) as 'Not Constructive' but the OP is protesting. What should I do?

Comment: Come here to solicit more close-votes - _closed_.

Comment: Nothing. You did the right thing by flagging, and you went above and beyond by explaining to the OP why you think the question wasn't a good fit for the site. He or she could have taken the opportunity to edit and improve his question based on your feedback. Arguing with you isn't particularly productive, and it's generally a waste of your time to argue back. As you've seen, if enough people agree with you, the question will get closed and your opinion will be vindicated in the end. If not, well, you were wrong; we all are sometimes.

Answer (score 12):

There are other people who have agreed with you and hence the post is closed now. You need not worry if the OP protests. If he is right, then he can vote to re-open and wait for other people in community to support him.

However, if OP is protesting, I dont think you can do anything better than explaining him why the post if not constructive. If OP is not convinced and you know that he is wrong, then you can just ignore and carry on to help other posts.